# Match two enum variants in one arm, binding field of one variant using Option?

Tags: rust, enums, pattern-matching

I'd like to match two variants of an enum in one match arm. There is one field that is "the same" in each, meaning that it has the same type, name and semantic meaning. (`field0: i32` in the example below.) I'd like to bind a local `&mut i32` to `field0` of the given variant. One variant also has a field that is not "shared" by the other. (`field1: String` in the example.) This I would like to bind to a local `Option<&mut String>`. Is there a neat way to do this?

```rust
enum Enum {
    Variant0 { field0: i32, field1: String },
    Variant1 { field0: i32 },
    Variant2,
}

fn mutate(value: &mut Enum) {
    match value {
        // Hopefully some pattern matching magic
        // to get a local &mut i32 and a local
        // Option<&mut String>.
    }
}

fn main() {
    mutate(&mut Enum::Variant0 {
        field0: 123,
        field1: "hello".to_string(),
    });

    mutate(&mut Enum::Variant1 { field0: 456 });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `field0` of both variants into the same binding with `|`.

```rs
match value {
    Variant0 { field0, .. } | Variant1 { field0 } => println!("{field0}"),
    _ => (),
}
```

However, your other requirement of `field1` doesn't really fit into this syntax, so you need to do it manually. If you only needed an `&` reference, you could do it in two match expressions, but that is unlikely to be any prettier.

```rs
let (field0, field1) = match value {
    Variant0 { field0, field1 } => (field0, Some(field1)),
    Variant1 { field0 } => (field0, None),
    Variant2 => return,
};
println!("{field0}, {field1:?}");
```

Comment: I added an alternative in the original post based on your first suggestion, using an additional `if let`. It looks surprisingly neat actually! I might go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [the question by Simplex](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76190619/2):

> This is the neatest alternative I know of so far:
>
> ```rust
> fn mutate(value: &mut Enum) {
>     match value {
>         Enum::Variant0 { field0, .. } | Enum::Variant1 { field0 } => {
>             // Mutate *field0 here.
>
>             if let Enum::Variant0 { field1, .. } = value {
>                 // Mutate *field1 here.
>             }
>         }
>         Enum::Variant2 => (),
>     }
> }
> ```